# Omit datetime.date from String

Tags: python, sql

The following query selects the date then three values from a database

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("host1","user","pass","db")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select report_date, ROUND(SUM(balance), 2) as 'Net', ROUND(SUM(short_mkt_value), 2) as 'Short', ROUND(SUM(int_balance ), 2) as 'Long' from intersum_recap where group_name = 'Carter' group by report_date order by report_date desc")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row
```

When it returns the date, it doesn't return 2018-3-29 as I would like, but instead returns "datetime.date(2018, 3, 29)"

What can I do to print my date in YYYY-MM-DD format as I would like to?

Comment: How are you printing that date? `import datetime; d = datetime.date(2018, 3, 29); print(d)` prints `2018-03-29` for me.

Comment: its part of the rows tuble, value row[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print a list as a unit the items in the list are converted to strings using their [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method. Instead, you want the `datetime.date` to use its [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method. There are a couple of different ways to make that happen. A fairly simple way is to use a list comprehension to convert all the items in the row into strings and then join them into a single string. Eg

```
print(', '.join([str(u) for u in row]))
```